# Fetching any particular text from Webview

Tags: android, uitableview, android-layout, webview, android-webview

I am new to webview in android. I just want to know the way how we can fetch any particular text from webview if the text is available there.

Example: I have some text on my webview like "Android works great" Here I want if the text "Android" is available on webview then do something else otherthing.

```
if("Android" available on webview) {
then Print("It works great")
}
else {
Print ("Useless")
}
```

How I can attain the same in Android.
Please help me out.
**Thanks in Advance :)**

Comment: you need to parse html tags using to extract text and then print the same.

Comment: Please check this link to fetch the text in webview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579772/android-get-text-out-of-webview

Comment: @aniketkulkarni Not working for me

Answer (score 2):

It's not the best way to do it but you can get the url content and then compare it to your text

```
try {                   
                URL url;
                url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");

                BufferedReader in;

                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));                   

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(inputLine.contains("Android")) {

                    } else {

                    }
                }
                in.close();

            } catch(Exception e) {                  
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: i tried it in one of my app and it was working, but you need to run it in an asynctask or you will get a networkingonuithread exception