# Using loadUrl to get all select options in a drop down box

Tags: java, javascript, android

I'm trying to store all values from a drop down box into variables within my android application. I'm trying to get all options from the below into strings in my app;

```
<select name="cardId" id="select_card_no" onfocus="null" onchange="null">
<option value="">Choose card number</option>
<option value="010607655930" >010607655930</option>
<option value="050538806749" >050538806749</option>
<option value="054100790989" >054100790989</option>
</select>
```

I've been using code like this to intially log through parts of the site;

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(url == "https://oyster.tfl.gov.uk/oyster/entry.do"){             
                    String ausername = "abcde";
                    String apassword = "12345";
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('j_username')[0].value = '"+ausername+"'");
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('j_password')[0].value = '"+apassword+"'");
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.forms[0].submit()");
                }
```

But was wondering how you could possibly get text back from the current Webview state, can you somehow convert **loadUrl** into a string;

```
String ddl = view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('select_card_no')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate question.  You may want to check out the answer to this one:

[android - get Text out of webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579772/android-get-text-out-of-webview)

Also, there might be an overall better solution than using this webview approach you're trying.  That url does have a developer api:  [android - get Text out of webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579772/android-get-text-out-of-webview)

You may want to try and see if you can get waht you need out of that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i saw that link the second after I posted this, but you said you saw a developer API for this? I know their general API but haven't seen one for the Oyster card as of yet!

Comment: You know what - all i saw was the general API.  So, not really sure they have an api for exactly what you need.