# How to get value from textbox of webview in android?

Tags: java, android, webview

Hello I want to know that is there any way to get value from `webview` html element or not. 
I did load page in `webview` as follows

```
package example.samplewebview; 

import android.annotation.SuppressLint; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.webkit.WebView; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView wv;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        wv.get
    }
}
```

and with this google.com page is loaded in `webview`.
now i want to get value from that search `textbox` and store in database
any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Take a look at Selendroid. I reckon that'll be able to do it.

Comment: As Far as My knowledge on Selenadroid its an testing framework.may you please provide some more specification. about how it can be used.

Comment: I do not know exactly how Selendroid works (I work only with selenium), but though it's often used for testing purposes, it gives the possibility to interact with a browser, including extracting information from a website. On selendroids site, it states it can interact with Androids WebView as well. Which means it should be suitable for your needs. Just Google selendroid. I think it should work.

Comment: thanks man,i did google for it, and there is one webdriver class in api but they have not provide documentation for it. so its seems ver hard to implement it.
Anyway  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are not Google, but you do want to use your own website, which you can modify, I suggest that you place a javascript on your webpage, that calls a native method inside your Android app and just submitts the value from this textfield.

There is already a thread on that topic here: [android - get Text out of webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579772/android-get-text-out-of-webview)

Comment: Actually i already read this thread but submits the value to web server.
I want that value at backend in java's activity extended class

Comment: the first answer passes data to the native android layer if the page has loaded. You may want to pass data to the android layer if the user presses a button or similar. Till that point the answer points you in the right direction.

Comment: view.loadUrl("javascript:window.INTERFACE.processContent(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText);"); 

in this load url has void type so i cant do
string s=view.loadUrl("javascript:window.INTERFACE.processContent(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText);");

if that textbox value is lying on android layer then how can i store in variable of android (java)

Comment: Thanks for link,i will try to figure out.