# How to get the value entered in EditText of android WebView page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am developing a application where I want to get values entered by user in webpage of android WebView. How we get the data entered in EditText of webpage.
Thanks

Comment: You can enable javascript in webview and can get the value from webpage to native java using javascript function.

Comment: The mobile application should read data entered by user.

Comment: Maybe this might help. [Stack Overflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579772/android-get-text-out-of-webview)

Comment: @SwapnilMeshram But how to get data from particular edittext. I mean to say, how will we know the id of edittext.

Comment: hi @pradippatle use this code to get data of perticular edittext and see below code for brief:  String  at = document.getElementById("email").value;

Comment: Thanks @Manish Can you please tell me where to put/place HTML and JavaScript code provided by you.

Comment: in assets folder @pradippatle

Comment: if its not exists in recourse directory then add assets folder and put html file

Comment: @Manish Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: ok, if my answer is helpful to you then accept it and upvote to maintain the decorum of stackoverflow @pradippatle

Answer (score 0):

here is java code:

```
wv_load.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
            {
                @JavascriptInterface
                public void performClick(String strName,String strAge,String strEmail)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(WebActivity.this, "Input Provided "+strName+" "+strAge+" "+strEmail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, "valid");
```

and html with javascript code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script language="javascript">

   var at;
   var age;
   var name;

   function validClick()
   {
      at = document.getElementById("email").value;
      age = document.getElementById("age").value;
      name = document.getElementById("name").value;

      document.getElementById('lbl').innerHTML = '';
      document.getElementById('lbl2').innerHTML = '';
      document.getElementById('lbl3').innerHTML = '';

      var ret=myValidation();

      if(ret==true){

      valid.performClick(name,age,at);

      document.getElementById('lbl').innerHTML = '';
      document.getElementById("demo_form").reset();

      }else{

      }

   }

   function myValidation() {

    submitOK = "true";

    if (!validateName(name)) {
        document.getElementById('lbl').innerHTML = 'Enter Full Name!';
        submitOK = "false";
    }

    if (isNaN(age) || age < 1 || age > 100) {
        document.getElementById('lbl2').innerHTML = 'Enter Valid Age!';
        submitOK = "false";
    }

    if (!validateEmail(at)) {
        document.getElementById('lbl3').innerHTML = 'Enter Valid Email!';
        submitOK = "false";
    }

    if (submitOK == "false") {

        return false;
    }
    else{

        return true;

    }
    }

    function validateName(name){
    var reName=/^(([A-Za-z]+[\-\']?)*([A-Za-z]+)?\s)+([A-Za-z]+[\-\']?)*([A-Za-z]+)?$/;
    return reName.test(name);
    }

    function validateEmail(at) {
       var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
       return re.test(at);
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="demo_form" id="demo_form">
    Name : <input type="text" id="name" style="margin-left: 16px;" size="20">
    <label id="lbl" style="color:red"></label><br>
    Age : <input type="text" id="age" style="margin-left: 30px;" size="20">
    <label id="lbl2" style="color:red"></label><br>
    Email: <input type="text" id="email" style="margin-left: 22px;" size="20">
    <label id="lbl3" style="color:red"></label><br><br>

    <div>
        <button type="button" id="ok" style="font-weight: 700; margin-left: 70px;"
                onclick="validClick();">Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```