# Android: Enter text to input field of websites programmatically?

Tags: android

Is it possible from an Android App within Android Runtime to enter text in a texfield of a website and
trigger a button click on that site programmatically?
This little App has a Button, after clicking that Button  chrome is opened with a website.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String url = "https://www.bahn.de/p/view/index.shtml";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This website has textfields to enter text. But how can they be accessed?

Comment: Have a look into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9581016/3967525

Comment: Thanks, will check that.

Comment: Ah I see, you can read text from a website. But I still don't understand how to enter text to a textfield of a website programmatically :/

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically submit a form to a webserver?

Comment: What I am trying: on button click the App shall open chrome, go to a website, say google.com, enter some text in the searchfield, and then trigger seach button click. I know in this case it is possible to just open the url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=sushi", but I am trying to do it programmatically.